# How to find and replace string in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, replace, find

I have something like this

```
No. | Incorrect_Keyword | Correct Keyword

1 | flash | Flash Player

2 | flash player | Flash Player

3 | flash player plugin | Flash Player

4 | flash player plgin | Flash Player
```

It's saved in csv file and I use PHP to read each line and replace

The problem is when I run query

```
$query="UPDATE keyword SET keyword= REPLACE(keyword, 'incorrect_keyword',  'correct_keyword') WHERE INSTR(keyword, 'incorrect_keyword') > 0";
```

It replace all the "flash" to "Flash Player"
So record number 2 will become "FLash Player player"
How to make it right? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you've to remove all flash values to Flash Player than you can simply use like query..

```
UPDATE `keyword` set `keyword` = 'Flash Player' where `keyword` like '%flash%';
```

Comment: if simple like this, keyword "flash player" also be replaced to "Flash Player player"

Answer (score 0):

You have to use LIKE instead of INSTR

So your query must be something like below

```
UPDATE keyword SET keyword= REPLACE(keyword, 'incorrect_keyword',  'correct_keyword') WHERE `keyword` LIKE CONCAT('%',`incorrect_keyword`,'%');
```

supposed incorrect_keyword and keyword are column names

Comment: still the same error, when query one by one line, flash -> Flash Player, flash player ->  Flash Player player. Incorrect keyword No.2 can't not replace in another table because it now become Flash Player player

Comment: Can you provide the structure of your table

Comment: The table I mentioned above is for the PHP script to read one by one line to replace correct keyword for another column(software) in another table(software). The record in column (software) is like this: "flash", "flash player plugin", "flash player plugin, chrome", "flash player plugin, chrme". It get data from user typing so sometime it not correct. Now I need to replace it with correct format

Comment: If I run the script with that query, record from column(software) become "Flash Player", "Flash Player player plugin", "Flash Player player plugin, Google Chrome"

Answer (score 0):

Add a ORDER BY for the UPDATE:

```
$query="UPDATE keyword SET keyword= REPLACE(keyword, `incorrect_keyword`,  `correct_keyword`) WHERE INSTR(keyword, 'incorrect_keyword') > 0" ORDER BY No DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Some php equivalent of ucwords is here.

https://www.thingy-ma-jig.co.uk/blog/30-09-2010/mysql-how-upper-case-words

A bit tedious but should be helpful.